# JSON Parse Swift [Google Translate API]

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, google-translate

I'm developing a Translator App on Menubar for MacBooks.

**Problem:**

I can't parse JSON results from Google Translate API.

Example JSON result:

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "Hello World"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Please help me!

Edit : Add my codes

http://imgim.com/ekranresmi2015-06-21112615.png

and i use SwiftHTTP for http requests. 
https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP

Comment: What have you tried until now ? Do you have any sample code that you did and did not work ?

Comment: Please PLEASE DON'T UPLOAD SCREENSHOTS OF YOUR CODE!!! You just broke my programming heart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem use SwiftyJSON :)

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1):

I hope according to your given screenshot of your code sample your JSON string is containeed within the `str` variable. So solution would be something like as follows:

```
NSString *translatedText = str["data"]["translations"][0]["translatedText"];
```

I suggest you to read the following given tutorial link.

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial

Comment: but this is Objective-C code. i try different combination but i can't .